# Blender 2.91 Cycles: Why is the render result different from the viewport rendered view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I am following Blender Guru's mars tutorial and making a surface with rocks using two particle systems. One using bigger rocks and one using smaller rocks, both are collections of objects. The render result was fine at first but as I altered the rocks in the collection and made other changers, the smaller rocks disappear in the render.
In the 3D viewport rendered view, it still looks fine, like this:
[image: 3D viewport rendered view]

but in the rendered result, there is like only 10% of the small rocks rendered. (Big rocks hided and material was adjusted to shrink the file size)
[image: render result (JPEG)]

Does it has something to do with having two particle systems on one mesh? Because the plane in the back with only one particle system looks fine.

Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: make sure that the camera icon is enabled on the top of the Particle panel

Comment: Yes it is, but it seems that only one of them is rendered...

Comment: It seems like some of your rocks visibility is disabled in the Outliner, is it your problem here? Click on the funnel icon and click on the camera icon to display the Disable in Renders option

Comment: By the "funnel icon" do you mean the green one? and "camera icon" is it the render properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some of your rock visibilities are disabled in the *Outliner*. Click on the funnel icon and click on the camera icon to display the *Disable in Renders* option:

[image]

Comment: I think that's it! Thanks!